# Set up code coverage with CherryPy?

Tags: python, code-coverage, cherrypy

I can see from the documentation that there is a module named covercp.

It says to "simply" put the line:
    cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start', covercp.start)

but when I do that it tells me that covercp is not defined.

Clearly I need to set something up, but I don't understand what.

What I really want is a simple example that shows setting it up, and viewing the results.  But my google searching has turned up nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try importing covercp?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I tried import covercp, from CherryPy import covercp.   Any other incantations to try?

Comment: It may not be exposed through the root cherrypy module, did you try importing it from the lib submodule where it's defined per [the docs](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/_modules/cherrypy/lib/covercp.html)?

Comment: I am now importing it successfully (from cherrypy.lib import covercp).   however, I still can't get it to work.   When I try python on the covercp.py, I get   line 377, in serve
    if coverage is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'coverage' referenced before assignment

Comment: Hi, please file a bug on GitHub to have it properly tracked.

Comment: (because we don't test it and it *might* be broken)